# Config files for GAC assemblies using Wix

Tags: wix, configuration-files, gac

I know this has been asked a few times in the past. And I have read all the responses and answers and none of them seem appropriate.

I've tried putting the .config in the same component and in a different component.
I've tried CompanionFile in the same component and in a different component.
I've tried CopyFile.
I've tried a Custom Action.

The component needs to be in the GAC because it is a general logging dll used by many different subsystems (services, websites, etc). But it is configured the same for all systems.

So for now I'm installing the file to a SDK directory and telling the user to copy the file.

The ONLY thing that works is copying the file manually and saying yes to "you need admin perms to do this".

```
<File Id="SDK.Logging.dll.config"
      Source="$(var.LOGGER_DIR)\SDK.Logging.dll.config"
      Vital="yes">
</File>

<Property Id="XCOPY">xcopy.exe</Property>
<CustomAction Id="Copy.SDK.Logging.dll.config"
              Property="XCOPY"
              ExeCommand='"[INSTALLLOCATION]SDK.Logging.dll.config" "[GAC.SDK.Logging.Dir]"' />
```

Comment: It seems you answered your question in the question itself. Are you asking for alternatives to do the same thing?